# Parsing complicated JSON request in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, parsing

I'm developing a RESTful service using Java and Spring-Boot and ran into a problem. I'm getting a put request with request body like:

```
    {
     "key":{
       "par1":"val1",
       "par2":"val2"
      },
     "data":{
        "par1":"val1",
        "par2":"val"
      }
   }
```

For parsing it I need to create own @RequestBody type. This is it:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.JSONWrappedObject;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

public class UpdateInfo {

    private Map<String, Object> mapKey;
    private Map<String, Object> mapData;

    ObjectMapper mapper;

    public void setMapKey(JsonNode key) {
        this.mapKey = mapper.convertValue(key,  new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
    }

    public void setMapData(JsonNode) {
        this.mapData = mapper.convertValue(data,  new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getKeys() {
        return mapKey;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getData() {
        return mapData;
    }

}
```

Logically it must work, but I am getting an error:

```
    [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: null; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 3] (through reference chain: com.sas.rus.spm.UpdateInfo["key"])]
```

Really can't get the reason, hope for your help

Comment: will your keys and data object always have these 2 keys with the same name? IE : par1 and par2 as mentioned here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try:

```
public class UpdateInfo {

    private Map<String, Object> key;
    private Map<String, Object> data;
    //getter and setter

    public Map<String, Object> getKey(){
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Map<String,Object> key){
         this.key = key
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Map<String,Object> data){
         this.data = data
    }

}
```

Comment: and then how should the setter look like? what argument will it have?

Comment: @Turlarion a map.

Comment: can you give a short example? I still don't understand the argument's type

Comment: @Turlarion use the standard getter and setter

Answer (score 0):

**JSON parse error: null** it is just because you din't initialize mapKey and mapData and getter method is returning null.

Also change the **getKeys() method to getKey()** as in json your json key is key.

Your class will look like

```
public class UpdateInfo {

private Map<String, Object> mapKey = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String, Object> mapData = new HashMap<>();

ObjectMapper mapper;

public void setMapKey(JsonNode key) {
    this.mapKey = mapper.convertValue(key, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
    });
}

public void setMapData(JsonNode data) {
    this.mapData = mapper.convertValue(data, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
    });
}

public Map<String, Object> getKey() {
    return mapKey;
}

public Map<String, Object> getData() {
    return mapData;
}
}
```